# Dropbox on Ubuntu seems to be impossible

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

#### In brief

With the aim to mount dropbox folder under Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) I followed a procedure (see below) and I stopped when I could not find the command `dbxfs`.
Shouldn't it be somewhere? I mean, it's got to be a file, right?

---

#### Some words more

Wow, I thought this would be easy with all the hits I got in my initial search.

I want to mount a dropbox folder while using the latest (18.04LTS) Ubuntu. Although I found a zillion opinions that the best thing to do is use the web interface on Linux, well, that doesn't help for those of us who have a ton of files that need processing. (I know, that's not what dropbox is for, but coming from Mac OS X, that's my workflow).

I found a result called CLOUDFUSION that I didn't realize was several years old. That explains why a couple of packages were no longer around.

Some people referred me to GNOME-ONLINE-ACCOUNTS which has apparently removed Dropbox support

I found another called FF4D that used FUSE and python. Huzzah! Except its only directions were for a "Quick Start" which is not a lot of help when nothing starts.

The most promising is a solution called DBXFS, whose directions are on a page less than eight weeks old (it's dated OCT 2018, and it's currently DEC 2018: https://www.ostechnix.com/dbxfs-mount-dropbox-folder-locally-as-virtual-file-system-in-linux/). I go through every direction with care. I look closely for any error. Every package is found. Nothing but white in the terminal.

But when it comes to the point of executing the command $ dbxfs I get "command not found". Here I am having completed the rest of the page, generating tokens and whatall, to no avail.

I realize that my git skills are limited to simple things like cloning, and that my understanding of FUSE is limited, but I can't believe I've spent an hour installing and upgrading tons and tons of things to still have no solution.

I very well may be misunderstanding what I'm to do. I searched my filesystem with everything I know to use to find "dbxfs", and it's nowhere. Shouldn't it be somewhere? I mean, it's got to be a file, right?

The task I need dropbox for is that I want to host a calibre library on my unused ubuntu machine. But the 1TB of books are on DropBox, and until I can see them, I'm at a standstill.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Try to be specific in order to obtain an appropriate answer. many people in these sites love the "One problem, one question". BTW It seems to be a python script `pip3 install dbxfs`. Did you do that step?

Comment: Please, [edit] your post adding which steps were successful and which ones failed... it can help... I found a python script in `$HOME/.local/bin/dbxfs`. Ask to your shell `file ~/.local/bin/dbxfs` and it should answer you `Python script, ASCII text executable`. That should answer to your question... and you may want to post another question (I know)... `:-)`

Comment: Hashtur: I did do that step. That's what made me think it was a file, and I was surprised when I couldn't find it.

Well, I say I couldn't find it...I always have to look up the argument to the find command when I use it, as I don't usually trust the GUI search.

Comment: I assume I can't reply to you directly because I'm new here?

Anyway, you were spot on. That's where the script was.

I went through the same install process on my (normally picky) ubuntu laptop, and all went fine, which added to my frustration. All is well, and thanks!

Comment: "Indeed you did" (I liked the sound of this phrase...`:-)`). Well, when someone answers to your comment (just after) or to a question, it is notified to the _"owner"_. You can directly address a comment to someone among the other comments with `@` before the name. But you have not to misspell it `!`. Do not let it discourage, do not let anything discourage. I will add the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Shouldn't it be somewhere? I mean, it's got to be a file, right?

Yes it is a file, a python script, under a path hidden under your home directory

```
file $HOME/.local/bin/dbxfs
Python script, ASCII text executable
```

#### Some words more

From the link you provided there is a step that may point you in the right direction...

```
pip3 install dbxfs
```

[Pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager))  *is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python*.
Now `pip3` is often already installed, if not you can always do it with commands like

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

If you install dbxfs via pip you will probably find it in the path `$HOME/.local/bin/dbxfs`. 
With `file $HOME/.local/bin/dbxfs` your shell will answer you that is a `Python script, ASCII text executable`.

You may find further interesting news asking from the shell

```
man pip
man pip3
man file
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem but finally got it to work. What I did was to use the "long name" for dbxfs, I just ran:

```
/home/your_username/.local/bin/dbxfs /home/your_username/your_mountPoint/
```

Then followed the rest of steps as in https://www.ostechnix.com/dbxfs-mount-dropbox-folder-locally-as-virtual-file-system-in-linux/

It worked very nice. Hope this helps.